# Prevent multiline HTML output from TSX/JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx, tsx

Within a React project using Typescript, rendering multiple variables within a components render, results in multiline HTML output.

This doesn't cause any real issues, the view is as expected and testing libraries are able to use `findByText` without an issue.

When you inspect the page, you see:

```html
<p>
    "Foo"
    ": "
    "Bar"
</p>
```

The code that would produce the above example, is within the return of a functional component.

```
const FooBar = ({foo, bar}) => (
    <p>
        {foo}: {bar}
    </p>
);
```

I would expect the output to be consistent with this and concatenate the variables into a single line.

Is there a reason that the output is not concatenated? Is there a way to force a single line output?

Comment: Why do you need a single TEXT node, though? Dev tools shows you the DOM node tree (not HTML), and shows you that React builds separate TEXT nodes because that's by far the most sensible way to generate a text sequence consisting of "raw text" and "templated data". If you need the text content client side, your app already knows what is because it literally builds that content already, so that's not a problem. And if you absolutely need it outside of yuour app, the `.textContent` properly already yields a single string, not an array of text nodes, so... there is no problem here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to group them together before HTML is generated.

```
const FooBar = ({foo, bar}) => (
    <p>
        {`${foo}: ${bar}`}
    </p>
);
```